# Search for an ambiguous outlook recipient with python

Tags: python, outlook, win32com

I am trying to use python to search for an outlook recipient using this code:

```
import win32com.client

search_string = 'name'
outlook = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Outlook.Application')
recipient = outlook.Session.CreateRecipient(search_string)
recipient.Resolve()
print('Resolved OK:', recipient.Resolved)
print('Name: ' , recipient.Name)
ae = recipient.AddressEntry
email.address = None

if 'EX' == ae.Type:
    eu = ae.GetExchangeUser()
    email_address = eu.PrimarySmtpAddress

if 'SMTP' == ae.Type:
    email_address = ae.Address

print('Email Address: ' , email_address)
```

The problem is when the search returns more then one result i cannot resolve the name,
I would like to receive a list of the results which the user can choose from in case there is more then one result how do i do that?

Comment: Is it returning the correct email addresses?

Comment: Yes if there is only one match

Answer (score 0):

Outlook Object Model won't let you search for multiple matches: it either finds a unique match, or returns an error if not matches are found or if more than one march exists.

On the Extended MAPI level (C++ or Delphi only) you can create a `PR_ANR` restriction on the contents table of a particular search container (such as GAL). That is what Outlook does when it resolves a name you typed in the To edit box - it goes through all containers in the search path and applies the `PR_ANR` restriction. If there are multiple matches found, it displays a dialog box with the list. If there is a single match, it is returned and the search is stopped, otherwise it continues to the next container in the search path.

If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author - any language) is an option, it exposes [RDOAddressBook](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdoaddressbook.htm).ResolveNameEx and [RDOAddressList](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAddressList.htm).ResolveNameEx, which return a list of matches.

In VB script:

```
  set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
  Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
  set AdrrEntries = Session.AddressBook.ResolveNameEx("john")
  Debug.Print AdrrEntries.Count & " names were retruned by ResolveNameEx:"
  Debug.Print "------------"
  for each AE in AdrrEntries
    Debug.Print AE.Name
  next
  Debug.Print "------------"
```

Comment: How do i implement it in python?

Comment: Do you mean how to convert the VB script above to Python?